# After developing Laravel in VPS, only the main page is loaded

Tags: laravel, vps, ubuntu-server

I finally managed to load my laravel project on my vps and everything was going well until I noticed that except for the home page, all other pages were returning a 404 error.
I did all these instructions but it didn't fix it.

```
php artisan view:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:cache
php artisan key: generate
```

But the other pages were not loaded at all. The rewrite module is also active

Comment: Do not cache routes. clear route cache by running cmd ``php artisan route:clear`` and try. Also is the project hosted in a subfolder?

Comment: yes,but does't work, project directory = /var/www/html/myproject/public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, enable rewrite mode

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then

```
nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Change Following

```
<Directory /var/www/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Into

```
<Directory /var/www/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then again restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**If this is not working change the `your-domain.conf` file following the above steps.**

this file will be located at

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/your-domain.conf
```

As I see in your comment, the above file will contain a code block like

```
<Directory /var/www/html/myproject/public>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Change it into

```
<Directory /var/www/html/myproject/public>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Finally

```
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I did all these things and it still didn't work

Comment: @johnDoe220 could you add `your-domain.conf` and the some result of `php artisan route:list`

Comment: what you mean ?

Comment: @johnDoe220 apache configuration file